# Determine if the currently open page is a replica of a parent page which was opened in a new tab

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, razor

I am trying to write a simple javascript/jquery to find out if the given page is opened from a parent page in a new tab and that the page is replica of the parent page.

I have come across methods with checks  like `(typeof(opener) != "undefined")` and `window.parent.location==window.location`. But they don't seem to the solution.

Anyone has a clue on this?

Any solution in Javascript/Jquery or Razor view engine would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing `window.parent.location == window.location` will return `false`, comparing two different objects, even with same properties, while comparing `window.parent.location.href == window.location.href` will return `true`, comparing two strings, same URL.

So if i understand what you are looking for, you should compare `href` property between both objects.

Comment: Hi A.Wolff Thanks for the answer. However using your approach that will return true even if the window was loaded for first time which should be false to be honest because i believe there will not be a parent window for that document when it is loaded for the first time.

Comment: You should provide a jsFiddle because honestly I'm not sure to understand what you are looking for here